# How is this formula for the Dirichlet $\beta$-function derived?

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, beta-function

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function), we have:

$${\displaystyle \beta (2k)={\frac {1}{2(2k-1)!}}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty }\left(\left(\sum _{l=0}^{k-1}{\binom {2k-1}{2l}}{\frac {(-1)^{l}A_{2k-2l-1}}{2l+2m+1}}\right)-{\frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{2m+2k}}\right){\frac {A_{2m}}{(2m)!}}{\left({\frac {\pi }{2}}\right)}^{2m+2k},}$$

where ${\displaystyle A_{k}}$ is the Euler zigzag number.

However, the citation is missing on Wikipedia. Is there an easy way to derive this, or alternatively, a link to a paper with a proof?

Comment: Contour integral, residue theorem, definition of $A_k$ as the Taylor coefficients of a trigonometric function

Comment: @reuns To the point as usual. If you could (rigorously) expand that thought, I might even throw in some extra points.

Comment: One source online is http://vixra.org/pdf/1608.0429v1.pdf, with the desired result following from substituting equation (8) into equation (22). (The similarity of the notation to the Wikipedia page makes me wonder if this is indeed where it was obtained from.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you, that's interesting. I'm usually very skeptical of vixra papers, has this been published somewhere else?

Comment: That's my reaction to vixra as well, but I haven't yet been able to find any other source. That being the case, It may be worth posting the relevant derivation from that source (as a CW answer, perhaps) so that other users can directly assess its validity.